# Google Could Platform failed to load VM instance

Tags: google-cloud-platform

I was trying to create VM instance on [Google Could Platform](https://console.cloud.google.com/), but it always gives me an error says `Failed to load`.

================

**Answer**

Found the solution by accident, I was browsing in the `MarketPlace` and trying to launch a `Ubuntu 16.04 OS` but end with this error

> Compute Engine API has not been used in project xxxxxxxxxxx before or
>   it is disabled. Enable it by visiting
>   https://console.developers.google.com/apis/api/compute.googleapis.com/overview?project=xxxxxxxxxxx
>   then retry. If you enabled this API recently, wait a few minutes for
>   the action to propagate to our systems and retry.

So I goto the link mentioned in the above Error message. After I enabled `Compute Engine API` there I can find the `Create Instance` button in my `VM instances` section.

[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This error message is related to UI issues with cache and cookies. So to fix this you can try any of the following:

1.- Log In to GCP in an Incognito window. 
2.- Clear/delete your web browser cache and cookies. 
3.- Login to GCP through another web browser.

Please verify Compute Engine API is enabled in your project by following step 3 from this [guide](http://cloud.google.com/compute/docs/quickstart-linux).

Additional, there was a known issue yesterday that prevent new projects to enable Compute Engine API and therefore not be able to create VM Instances. This issue has been fixed by now so you shoud be able to create this Instances with no problem.

Comment: Thanks, that is what I thought in the first place, I even tried with another Browser but without any luck.

Comment: Hello Alan, Please verify Compute Engine API is enabled in your project by following step 3 from this guide [1]. If you still encounter some issue creating a VM instance please create a PIT [2]. Let me know how it works. 

[1] https://cloud.google.com/compute/docs/quickstart-linux
[2] https://cloud.google.com/support/docs/issue-trackers#trackers-list

Comment: Jujosiga, you're right. The Computer Engine API is not enabled by default. Already updated the info in the question.

Comment: Perfect if you find the answer helpful please upvote it ;)